# Ajax not updating my search list

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I'm using MVC 5 C# and I'm trying to update my search filter on key strokes through AJAX. By code it works but the results aren't showing up on testing. I've done some debugging and in my view the results are being thrown in the view as shown:[image]

It's supposed to be displayed right underneath the search box but shows nothing.

[image]

Not quite sure what the issue is. So I'll list my code. Here is my Ajax.

```
<p>
Search Employee: <input type="text" name="userName" onkeyup="filterTerm(this.value);" />
</p>

<script>
    function filterTerm(value) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Directory")',
            data: {
                userName: value
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {


            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Ajax has been tested and is working, now in my controller it also is returning results (obviously is being pulled back to the View but just showing results). [image]
But here is my controller anyways:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string userName)
{
    /**********Establish Connection********/
    DirectoryEntry dir = createDirectoryEntry();
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(dir);

    /****Refer to class constructor****/


    /********Create the List to store results in***************/
    List<ADUser> Users = new List<ADUser>();
    string DisplayName = "", SAMAccountName = "", Mail = "", Description = "", Department = "", TelephoneNumber = "", Fax = "";

    /*******Filter parameters************/
    search.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(anr=" + userName + "* ))";
    SearchResultCollection searchresult = search.FindAll();
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Displayname");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SAMAccountName");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Mail");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Description");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("TelephoneNumber");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Fax");
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Department");

    /*****************Filtering and populating the List****************/

    if (searchresult != null)
    {
        foreach (SearchResult iResult in searchresult)
        {
            ADUser userAttributes = new ADUser("", "", "", "", "", "", "");

            foreach (string PropertyName in iResult.Properties.PropertyNames)
            {
                foreach (Object key in iResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties[PropertyName])
                {
                    try
                    {
                        switch (PropertyName.ToUpper())
                        {
                              .....
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }

            Users.Add(userAttributes);
        }

        return View(Users);
    }

    return View();
}
```

It seems like it might just be something I'm missing that I don't know about.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Try changing `return View()` to `return PartialView()`. And you are not doing anything with the result (`success`) of your ajax call.

Comment: And for anyone else, see [the last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307268/search-method-issue) for where the ajax code came from.

Answer (score 0):

serialize your user list to json before return it to view as follow.

```
 using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(User);
return View(json)
```

and make your ajax's datatype json as follow :

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Directory")',
            data: {
                userName: value
            },
            dataType:"json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {


            }
    });
```

Comment: Also User should be Users. I think i'm getting the 500 error because my list is complex