# Filter a search onkeyup

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

I've been trying to update my search results in a textbox upon each key entered. I've done what was told in my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309545/ajax-not-updating-my-search-list/24309698#24309698) (This will also give a good background on what my situation is at)

I'm using Ajax in MVC 5 C#. I have the AJAX submitting correct information into my post controller. I have also debugged the controller and know it is trying to return my json data to my view.

[image]

However, I get no errors in C# and nothing is displayed in my View. But, using Fiddler I've noticed that I'm getting a 500 Error.[image]

I've looked up the issue and tried to extend the max length of the Json to almost max and still have the same error.

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
  </appSettings>
```

Any help on this error would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to return view from controller just JSON data 
so your controller should look like that :

```
public ActionResult Index(string userName)
{
....

retrun Json(Users)
}
```

and you don't have to serialize users controller will do that for you